# Django ModelFormSets: display each model object along with a field value in a form

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

This is something that I thought would be easy, but I haven't figured it out yet. I have a simple model called `Channel`. Here it is:

```
class Channel(models.Model):
    id = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(primary_key=True)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    disabled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I want the user to be able to see all of the channels, displayed by name, and select which ones to `disable` or `enable`. I've gotten close, here's my view (simplified):

```
def channel_setup(request):
    ChannelFormSet = modelformset_factory(
        models.Channel,
        fields=['disabled'],
        edit_only=True
    )
    formset = ChannelFormSet()
    context = {
        'formset': formset
    }
    return render(request, "channel_setup.html", context)
```

What it does is display a checkbox for every single channel in the database. Perfect! The problem is that all of them are labeled "Disabled:", so there's no way to discern which channel is which.

I'd like to display each channel *by name* next to each checkbox. I know there's a way to change the label, but I haven't figured out how to set the label equal to the Channel's name field value.
I could probably do some hacky magic with javascript to make it happen but there has got to be a way to just do this with Django, right?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, might as well post for anyone who might need it.
In the view, loop through each form and in the formset and assign it to the associated channel name.

```
def channel_setup(request):
    ChannelFormSet = modelformset_factory(
        models.Channel,
        fields=['disabled'],
        edit_only=True
    )
    formset = ChannelFormSet()

    for form in formset.forms:
        form.fields['disabled'].label = form.instance.name

    context = {
        'formset': formset
    }
    return render(request, "channel_setup.html", context)
```